# Error in loading main module angular 2 with hashlocation strategy set to true

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

The error does not explain too much but i'll write it

> Error: AppModule<@http://*******.********.com/app/main.js:73:17
>       
> @http://*******.********.com/app/main.js:65:18
>       
> @http://*******.********.com/app/main.js:1:1
>       
> @http://*******.********.com/app/main.js:1:1
>       
> ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://*******.********.com/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:203:19
>       
> Zone.prototype.run@http://*******.********.com/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:96:24
>       
> scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://*******.********.com/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:462:52
>       
> ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://*******.********.com/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:236:23
>       
> Zone.prototype.runTask@http://*******.********.com/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:136:28
>       
> drainMicroTaskQueue@http://*******.********.com/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:368:25
>       
> ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://*******.********.com/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:308:25
>       
>       Evaluating http://*******.********.com/app/main.js
>       
> Error loading http://*******.********.com/app/main.js

and at the line 73 in main.ts file I have this line

## Update

## Main.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { FormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule }   from '@angular/router';
import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './app.routes'
import {
     LocationStrategy,
     HashLocationStrategy
} from '@angular/common'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'
import { Component1 } from './components/component1.component' 
import { Component2 } from './components/component2.component' 
import { Component3 } from './components/component3.component' 
import { Component4 } from './components/component4.component'
import { Component5 } from './components/component5.component'

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule,
                 FormsModule,
                 HttpModule,
                 RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,{useHash:true})
               ],
  declarations: [Component1,
                 Component2
                 Component3
                 Component4
                 Component5
                 AppComponent
                 ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

the APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS come from an import and it is an array of `Routes`

## app.routes.ts

```
import { Routes }  from '@angular/router';

import { Component1 } from './components/component1.component'
import { Component2 } from './components/component2.component'
import { Component3 } from './components/component3.component'
import { Component4 } from './components/component4.component'
import { Component5 } from './components/component5.component'
import { Login } from './components/login/login.component'

const routes: Routes = [
        {
        path:'',
        redirectTo: '/login',
        pathMatch: 'full'
        },
        {
        path: 'component1',
        component: Component1
        },
        {
        path: 'component2',
        component: Component2
        },
        {
        path:'component3',
        component:Component3
        },
        {
        path:'component4'
        component:Component4,
        },
        {
        path:'component5',
        component:Component5
        },
        {
        path:'login',
        component:Login
        }
  ];


  export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = routes
```

if I run the application with npm start everything works right, but if I deploy the same application on an application server I get the error above, what I do wrong? I have the feeling the the routes are badly declared.

Comment: What is the error `*******`?

Comment: is the name of the site

Comment: can you please add the main.ts (typescript, not javascript) file?

Comment: Maybe there also exists some text that describes your issue?

Comment: I'll add the complete file but no i have no other text in the error.

Comment: And there is no error if you do not have `useHash:true`?

Comment: @PierreDuc I doesn't try it, but i really need to use the hash location strategy

Comment: even with the hashlocation strategy set to false, I get the same error, @yurzui I've basically pasted the exception.